# C# - Load Image only partial

Tags: c#, image, load, picturebox, partial

I have a problem regarding to a partial image load. Here is the current situation:
I have a huge form with a Backgroundimage. This form has no border, so I make my own "Windows-Style-Buttons" with hovering and glowing.
To make this glowing, the buttons are invincible and the backgroundimage of the form get a new backgroundimage (backgroundimage + glowing button, combined in a function)
But on slow PCs, the loading of the new huge backgroundimage takes much time and isnt anymore realtime...

So how can I make it, to load the new backgroundimage only partial, onle the small section with the glowing button? 
I can't make a small picturebox, because the form has many tooltips and related timers and events, so I have to do all again, which wouldn't be very "productive"

Regards Wonderwhy

Comment: This is really *not* the best way to do this in WinForms... It's going to be glacially slow and unbelievably painful.

Comment: I have WinForms. So is there no better way than change the backgroundimage with the "None"-Imagelayout?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms: A better approach would probably be to make your own button type and override OnPaint() to get the appearance you want (here you can draw out parts of the background image, if you want). If you want to stick with the background image, you can override OnPaint of the form and draw your custom buttons there.

If this is WPF, there is built in support for these kinds of effects.

Comment: I didn't know that I can draw out parts of the backgroundimage. I thought the image can't be bigger than the border of the button.
How can I make that in WinForms?